# searching child-parent in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a child-parent mapping in elastic search.
How would I go about searching for parents based on statistics of their children.

Example:

```
{
  'parent':{
    '_id':{
      'path':'parent_id'
    },
    'properties':{
      'parent_id':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'name':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'job':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'age':{
        'type':'integer'
      },

    }
  }
}{
  'child':{
    '_parent':{
      'type':'parent'
    },
    '_id':{
      'path':'child_id'
    },
    'properties':{
      'child_id':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'name':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'favorite_toy':{
        'type':'string'
      },
      'age':{
        'type':'integer'
      },

    }
  }
}
```

How would I:

1. get all the parents that have a child named 'bob'?
2. count all the parents that have a child named 'bob'?
3. get all the parents that have more than two children?
4. get all the parents that have 2 children older than 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) and 2) - you can simply wrap your query into has_child query:

```
{
  "has_child":{
    "type":"child",
    "query":{
      "match":{
        "name":"bob"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3) and 4) - I don't think this is possible at the moment.

Comment: Thanks alot, I guess I'll just have to update the parents with specific fields like 'number of children' when i index children then.

Comment: @imotov hi Igor, I am interested in #3 of original question, i were wondering if this was implemented since the time of your post. Please let me know

Comment: @user1631616 it's not implemented, but if you don't care about relevancy you can fake it using [constant_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) query on children (so all children return score, using `sum` [score_type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html#_scoring_capabilities) and by setting [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) to 2

Comment: Ty vm for your reply. Nop, don't care about relevancy at all. Will try to play with it latter tonight, if you an example of such it would be very useful :)