# Get all parents who has more then 'N' childern

Tags: elasticsearch

I have searched for the answer, but unfortunately could not find it.
I have an index that contains a type for a user:

```
    users: {
    properties: {

        loginKey: {
            type: string
        }

        timeZone: {
            type: long
        }
        maxEmailsPerWeek: {
            type: long
        }

        joinDate: {
            format: dateOptionalTime
            type: date
        }
        preferredEntityId: {
            type: long
        }
        partition: {
            type: long
        }
        postalCode: {
            type: string
        }
        nickName: {
            type: string
        }
        announcements: {
            type: long
        }

        gender: {
            type: string
        }

        birthDate: {
            format: dateOptionalTime
            type: date
        }
        firstName: {
            type: string
        }
        emailTestId: {
            type: long
        }
        emailStateDate: {
            format: dateOptionalTime
            type: date
        }
        lastName: {
            type: string
        }
        emailAddress: {
            type: string
        }
...
    }
}
```

and have a type of user's activity:

```
    activity: {
    _routing: {
        required: true
    }
    properties: {
        eventTimestamp: {
            format: dateOptionalTime
            type: date
        }
        userAgent: {
            type: string
        }
        recordType: {
            type: string
        }
        universalTrackingParams: {
            properties: {
                MODULE_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                TRACKING_CODE: { // this is a unique user identifier
                    index: not_analyzed
                    omit_norms: true
                    index_options: docs
                    type: string
                }
                SENDING_DOMAIN_PARAM: {
                    index: not_analyzed
                    omit_norms: true
                    index_options: docs
                    type: string
                }
                PRODUCT_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                TEST_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                MAILING_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                NEWS_LETTER_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                LINK_POSITION: {
                    type: integer
                }
                DECORATION_TIMESTAMP: {
                    type: string
                }
                SITE_ID: {
                    type: string
                }
                TEMPLATE_VERSION: {
                    type: string
                }
                ORIGINAL_LINK: {
                    index: not_analyzed
                    omit_norms: true
                    index_options: docs
                    type: string
                }
            }
        }
        ip: {
            index: not_analyzed
            omit_norms: true
            index_options: docs
            type: string
        }
    }
    _parent: {
        type: users
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to search for all parents who has more then `N` children, in other words I would want to get all user records that had an activity (more then `N` times) within given period of time (`eventTimestamp`)

Could someone suggest either the resouce i can read or the query that can accomplish that

**Update**
So this is what i came up for this (using index and types created by Sloan Ahrens below):

```
{
  "min_score": 2,
  "query": {
    "top_children": {
      "type": "order",
      "score": "sum",
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this will get me all customers who had at least 3 orders(thanks to imotov)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's admittedly not a completely satisfying solution since it requires two queries, but I think you can get what you want using facets.

Simplifying a little (and using schema/data from [this blog post](http://joelabrahamsson.com/grouping-in-elasticsearch-using-child-documents/), I'll first create a simple index with a parent/child relationship:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/orders" -d'
{
    "mappings": { 
        "customer": {},
        "order" : {
            "_parent" : {
                "type" : "customer"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

then add some data:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/orders/_bulk" -d'
{ "index" : { "_type" : "customer", "_id" : "john" } }
{ "name" : "John Doe" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "order", "_parent" : "john" } }
{ "date" : "2013-10-15T12:00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "order", "_parent" : "john" } }
{ "date" : "2013-11-15T12:00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "order", "_parent" : "john" } }
{ "date" : "2013-12-01T12:00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "customer", "_id" : "jane" } }
{ "name" : "Jane Doe" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "order", "_parent" : "jane" } }
{ "date" : "2013-11-20T12:00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "customer", "_id" : "bob" } }
{ "name" : "Bob Doe" }
{ "index" : { "_type" : "order", "_parent" : "bob" } }
{ "date" : "2013-09-20T12:00:00" }
'
```

and then I can facet `order`s on the `"_parent"` field, filtering the docs to be faceted on `date`:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/orders/order/_search " -d'
{
    "size": 0, 
    "facets": {
       "customers": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "_parent"
          },
          "facet_filter": {
              "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "from": "2013-11-01T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
          }
       }
    }
}'
```

which gives me the following response:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": []
   },
   "facets": {
      "customers": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 3,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "customer#john",
               "count": 2
            },
            {
               "term": "customer#jane",
               "count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I can then retrieve the `customer`s with a second query, using the ids that were returned:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/orders/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "ids": {
         "type": "customer",
         "values": [
            "john",
            "jane"
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

You would have to add your own logic between the last two steps, to decide which customers to retrieve based on result counts, but you might be able to make this method work in your context.

Here is a runnable example you can play with: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/9ebde72ccffa0dce654383ad4fb0a8451b74a9f7

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for. In a meantime i found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116711/searching-child-parent-in-elasticsearch/15121972#15121972 where it was said that neither #3 not #4 is doable at that time (that is precisely what i am looking for). I am wondering if anything has changed since that time

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. I don't think there is a straightforward, single-request way to do it, at least not yet. What I showed you could be adapted to solve both 3 and 4, but not unless you're willing to make two requests and do a little hacking in between. Alternatively, you could use some extra fields to keep up with the statistics you want, at index time.